Accessing a file from a docker container, that has been added by a base image from which the container image was built
I am trying to find a way to access a file added by a base image from the final image.
Example:
Dockerfile for base1:
FROM scratch
ADD myfile.tgz .

Dockerfile for final image:
FROM base1
FROM ubuntu
 
RUN tar -zxvf myfile.tgz

This obviously does not work and I get this error:

tar (child): myfile.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory

How can I make this work?
I was expecting that the final running container will have the file myfile.tgz inside it. But I see that there is no such file in the container.

Pls make your structure or your sample Dockerfile. But from your issue, I think, you must copy myfile.tgz to image container before run. For ex, add to your Dockerfile: COPY host/yourUrl/myfile.tgz myfile.tgz

You can't use multiple FROM lines to combine images.  (What should happen if both base images contain /lib/libc.so.6, but they're different?)  What you can do is COPY --from the file from one image to another.
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=base1 /myfile.tgz ./
RUN tar tvzf myfile.tgz

You'll most often see COPY --from as part of a multi-stage build setup, but if the image name isn't a named build stage in the same Dockerfile, Docker will interpret it as an image name instead.

This worked!! I was missing the "WORKDIR /app" line and the --from option in the copy. Thank you for your help!
